# Google+ Signin button login issue with specific ClientId

Tags: javascript, authentication, google-plus

I have 2 webapps that I used the Google+ Signin button with, one of them works fine the other one seems like it's logging me in but returns an authenticationResult (in my callback method) of 0.  I say it seems like it logged me in since I get a popup that says "Welcome back, you've already connected with this app via Google+ Sign-In as sean christe."

In my app in which everything is working, my authenticationResult in the signinCallback is a full blown javascript object - in the one that is not working it is just a 0.

The one thing that worries me is that there's a big difference in clientIds between the 2 apps.  In the app everything is working in, my clientId is only 12 numbers - in my app where the signin is returning 0, my ClientId is the initial 12 numbers plus a "-" followed by a 32 character alphanumeric string. It looks like all the examples only have the 12 numbers - also, my ClientID for the app that's not working has 3 javascript origins - my working one only has 1.  Is this ClientID normal? - I'm having problems finding documentation on it.

I'm using Google Endpoints in both apps - the one that's working the gapi object has all my endpoints populated - in the one that's not working my gapi object doesn't seem like it's filled in.

---

edit: for the comments below - my exact code is actually posted here: http://exposure101-development.blogspot.com/2013/07/initializing-angularjs-app-with-oauth2.html and the directive I've been using to do it is right here https://github.com/sirkitree/angular-directive.g-signin/blob/master/google-plus-signin.js.

The only thing that's different between the 2 apps is the clientIds - I took 2 screenshots - 1 of each app (they're only deployed locally - neither of them is out on AppEngine yet although one will be soon).  Here is the console output of the directive I'm using - where the 2nd in both is the actual authentication result.

1 (the one that is working correctly)
[image]

2 (the one that is returning a 0)
[image]

The reason you don't see success in the output is because my callback is as follows (this is really ugly code - just doing it for testing purposes):

```
// Callback for Google+ Sign-In
function signinCallback(authResult) {
  console.log(authResult);
  if (authResult['access_token']) {
    console.log('SUCCESS');
  } else if (authResult['error']) {
    console.log('ERROR');
  }
}
```

On the 2nd one the authResult is 0 so there's no properties in the object - I'm also not sure exactly why the 'ASYNCHRONOUSLY LOADING THE G+ SDK' is happening after the callback prints - in both of these the only thing that is different is the clientId.  I'm using the directive unedited (after realizing the entire post I made in my blog had been done better by the Google+ signin button (which I was unaware existed at the time))

---

Edit 9/25:

I switched from the G+ signin back to the Javascript oauth2/gapi login method and got a better error - it's giving me a 401 "Login Required".  I imagine this is why the authenticationResult is giving me a 0.  Not sure what to do with this.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in your logs for the one that is not working?

Comment: You'll need to include the code examples that you're using (hiding the client IDs). You need to also include examples showing the structure of the authorization result object. If possible, links to both apps too would be helpful.

The difference in client ID formats is normal.

Comment: I added a screenshot of both outputs - the exact directive I'm using is https://github.com/sirkitree/angular-directive.g-signin/blob/master/google-plus-signin.js - added an edit to show this in more detail